# How to add multiple sensors on this Python3 script?

Tags: python-3.x, gpio

I'm trying to control GPIO state using Bluetooth (using Bluetooth Terminal), involving both GPIO.output (on/off device) and GPIO.input (binary sensor). The script for the GPIO.input (sensor) part is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bluedot.btcomm import BluetoothServer
from signal import pause
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN)

def data_received(data):
  print(data)
  if(data == "device_on"):
    GPIO.output(16,GPIO.LOW)
  elif(data == "device_off"):
    GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)
  else:
    GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)

s = BluetoothServer(data_received)
state = None
while True:
  if GPIO.input(6) == 1:
    new_state = 'on1'
  else:
    new_state = 'off1' 
  if state != new_state:
      s.send( new_state + "\n")
      state = new_state

state2 = None
while True:
  if GPIO.input(12) == 1:
    new_state2 = 'on2'
  else:
    new_state2 = 'off2' 
  if state2 != new_state2:
      s.send( new_state2 + "\n")
      state2 = new_state2
```

By that, the GPIO.output part worked, but only one of the sensors worked (I know Python is known to only run 1 sensor, but I needed 2), the first one written above (the GPIO6 one). What should I change/add in the script so it can run both sensors (GPIO6 and GPIO12)? Or any other way so that the Bluetooth Terminal can access multiple Python programs (if I have to make separate script for the GPIO12 one).

Comment: As an alternative to Tristan's answer, you could take a look at multithreading. If the number of sensors grows it is the way to go.

Comment: OK, I'd check that out if I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue in your program flow. Python is procedural, not asynchronous, that is, the second while loop won't run until the first finishes, which it never will because you have "while True" and no break in its body.
Anyway, try this:

```
state = None
state2 = None
while True:
  # handle gpio 6
  if GPIO.input(6) == 1:
    new_state = 'on1'
  else:
    new_state = 'off1' 
  if state != new_state:
      s.send( new_state + "\n")
      state = new_state
  # handle gpio 12
  if GPIO.input(12) == 1:
    new_state2 = 'on2'
  else:
    new_state2 = 'off2' 
  if state2 != new_state2:
      s.send( new_state2 + "\n")
      state2 = new_state2
```

Comment: So far it works, thanks then.

Comment: @kevj, there is a button to accept the answer. This how you can thank the person who answered your question.